# Adding component.Why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The code below does exactly what I am trying to do, which is when I click a button add a component dynamically.

The thing is I want to make a function to add the component rather than the inline expression.But, it won't work.please somebody educate me.

```
<add-exercise :days="days" transition="fade" v-for="component in components" :exerciseplan_id="exerciseplan_id"></add-exercise>

<button v-if="components < 7" @click.prevent="components++">Add</button>
<button v-else="submit" transition="fade">Submit</button>

</template>


data() {

       return {

          components:1,

},
components:{ AddExercise },
```

the code that does not work

```
<button v-if="components < 7" @click.prevent="addComponent">Add</button>

methods: {
 addComponent: function(){
   return this.components++
}
}
```

Comment: your code seems fine, can you create an example on e.g. jsfiddle.net that demonstrates the (mis)behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your method. You don't need to return, just run the action you want, like this:

```
methods: {
  addComponent: function(){
    this.components++;
  }
}
```